# Connector design pattern?

Tags: android, oop, design-patterns

I want to connect several classes which are functioning separately but are related.

Lets say I am writing an app in which you can swipe to draw a chart. There are lots of classes in the app which are related and should be connected.

For example three of the classes are:

Swiper - responsible for interpreting the gesture of the user

Points - responsible for handling the points on the chart

ChartDrawer - responsible for drawing the chart on the screen

I want to know is there any design pattern such as a connector which can handle the relation and communication of these classes? Any way i can redesign in a better way or make mind more object oriented?

This is my ChartDraw class which extends a view:

```
public class ChartDraw extends View implements GestureReceiver {
    int chartYPosition;
    private int circleColor;
    private int circleRadius;
    int height;
    private float lastPointOnChart;
    private int lineColor;
    private int lineWidth;
    private Paint paint;
    private float tempPoint;
    int width;

    public ChartDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ChartDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ChartDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.lineWidth = 15;
        this.circleRadius = 20;
        this.lineColor = Color.parseColor("#1976D2");
        this.circleColor = Color.parseColor("#536DFE");
        this.lastPointOnChart = 0.0f;
        this.tempPoint = 0.0f;
        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.height = getHeight();
        this.width = getWidth();
        this.chartYPosition = this.height / 2;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.chartYPosition = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        this.paint.setStrokeWidth((float) this.lineWidth);
        this.paint.setColor(this.lineColor);
        canvas.drawLine(0.0f, (float) this.chartYPosition, this.tempPoint, (float) this.chartYPosition, this.paint);
        if (this.tempPoint > 20.0f) {
            this.paint.setColor(this.circleColor);
            canvas.drawCircle(20.0f, (float) this.chartYPosition, 20.0f, this.paint);
            drawTriangle(canvas, this.paint, this.tempPoint, this.chartYPosition);
        }
    }

    private void drawTriangle(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float startX, int startY) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(startX, (float) (startY - 20));
        path.lineTo(startX, (float) (startY + 20));
        path.lineTo(30.0f + startX, (float) startY);
        path.lineTo(startX, (float) (startY - 20));
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    public void onMoveHorizontal(float dx) {
        this.tempPoint = this.lastPointOnChart + dx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void onMoveVertical(float dy) {
    }

    public void onMovementStop() {
        this.lastPointOnChart = this.tempPoint;
    }
}
```

And this is My SwipeManager which is handling user gesture:

```
public class SwipeManager implements View.OnTouchListener {
    GestureReceiver receiver;
    private int activePointer;

    private float initX,
            initY;
    private long startTime,
            stopTime;

    private boolean resolving = false;
    private boolean resolved = false;

    private Direction direction;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (receiver == null) throw new AssertionError("You must register a receiver");
        switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
            case ACTION_DOWN:
                activePointer = motionEvent.getPointerId(0);

                initX = motionEvent.getX(activePointer);
                initY = motionEvent.getY(activePointer);

                startTime = new Date().getTime();
                break;

            case ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!resolving && !resolved) {
                    resolving = true;
                    float x = motionEvent.getX(activePointer);
                    float y = motionEvent.getY(activePointer);
                    direction = resolveDirection(x, y);
                    if (direction != Direction.STILL) {
                        resolved = true;
                        resolving = false;
                    } else {
                        resolving = false;
                        resolved = false;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                if (resolved) {
                    if (direction == Direction.HORIZONTAL)
                        receiver.onMoveHorizontal(motionEvent.getX(activePointer) - initX);
                    else receiver.onMoveVertical(motionEvent.getX(activePointer) - initY);
                }
                break;

            case ACTION_UP:
                resolved = false;
                receiver.onMovementStop();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Direction resolveDirection(float x, float y) {
        float dx = x - initX;
        float dy = y - initY;
        float absDx = Math.abs(dx);
        float absDy = Math.abs(dy);
        if (absDx > absDy + 10) {
            return Direction.HORIZONTAL;
        } else if (absDy > absDx + 10) {
            return Direction.VERTICAL;
        }
        return Direction.STILL;
    }

    public void setReceiver(GestureReceiver receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    private enum Direction {HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, STILL;}
}
```

And i didn't start the Points class because i was not sure about the architecture.

I want this Connector to register all the listeners for the classes and wait for a change and inform the corresponding class of the change, like new point added or swipe started and finished or any other event in the app.

Comment: don't apologyze, just edit the question so it could be answered

Comment: @AdamSkywalker How can i edit? I think i was pretty clear...

Comment: write some code and your expectations from this connector

Comment: Added some code and my expectations. hope it's good... @AdamSkywalker

Comment: I think the best suitable pattern for your case is Observer

Answer (score 2):

[Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) might be what you are looking for.

It is a pattern to tie a series of 'processing objects' in a 'chain' that can handle 'command objects'.

I could see you making command objects that encapsulate the touch events and then get passed through several processors and finally get 'processed' by the 'processing objects' which handle input detection/output generation for that particular 'command object'.

I don't know if this is -ideal-, but it is potentially valid.

Other related patterns to look into might be:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check these patterns

Answer (score 1):

Really what you're looking for here is an MVC-style architecture. Your application should (broadly speaking) be separated into 3 different areas:

- the Model, which is completely divorced from your presentation or communication concerns. It provides an API for interaction and can be tested entirely independently with a simple framework such as JUnit.
- the View, which is responsible for displaying the Model. It may be that a model can be displayed in different ways - in which case you get a single model and a few different views.
- the Controller, which is responsible for making changes to the Model in response to user (or other) input.

The important thing is that the three sets of components are *loosely-coupled* and that responsibilities are clearly separated. All three should communicated via well defined interfaces (perhaps using the Observer, Command and ChainOfResponsibility patterns). In particular, the Model classes should have no direct knowledge of any of the View or Controller classes.

So, you might have some Model/View classes like this...

```
public interface ChartListener {
    void notifyUpdate();
}

public interface Chart {
    void newPoint(Point p);

    Collection<Point> thePoints();

    void addListener(ChartListener listener);
}

public class ChartModel implements Chart {
    private final Collection<Point> points;
    private final Collection<ChartListener> listeners;

    public Collection<Point> thePoints() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(points);
    }

    public void newPoint(Point p) {
        thePoints.add(p);
        listeners.stream().forEach(ChartListener::notifyUpdate);
    }

    public void addListener(ChartListener cl) {
        listeners.append(cl);
    }
}

public PieChartViewer implements ChartListener {
    // All you colour management or appearance-related concerns is in this class.
    private final Chart chart;

    public PieChartView(Chart chart) {
        this.chart = chart;
        // set up all the visuals...
    }

    public void notifyUpdate() {
        for (final Point p:chart.thePoints()) {
            // draw a point somehow, lines, dots, etc,
        }
    }
}
```

Then you might have multiple different implementations of your View classes, utilising the `ChartListener` interface.

Your `Swipe` class seems like a Controller class, which would take a `ChartModel` implementation and then modify it in response to some input from the user.

Comment: Thanks i will check that in a bit.